# Finding a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading an example of how to find a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, which are written additively. The book then tries to see if (1,1) is a generator and says that since the operations are additive so is the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.
the book then shows

(1,1)=(1,1)

2(1,1)=(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,2)

3(1,1)=(1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)=(1,0)

4(1,1)=3(1,1)+(1,1)=(1,0)+(1,1)=(0,1)

and so on. My question is how is the above computation calculated? Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the first coordinate, numbers add like in $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$. In the second, they add like in $Z / 3Z$. That is the meaning of the direct product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for example

$$4(1,1)=(4\pmod2,\,4\pmod3)=(0\pmod2,\,1\pmod 3)=(0,1)$$

where the rightmost last expression is just a short handed one that should be clear when each coordinate is taken the correspondent modulo.

Comment: thank you makes perfect sense